# Parse-Server : Error when executing save Parse Objects with Parse.Cloud.when

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-server

I'm migrating our app on parse.com to parse-server application on AWS.
There is a problem on my code below though this is working on parse.com

This function is save post with text and picture from iOS devices.
The last part of "savePostComment" seems to occur error.

The parse-server's version is 2.2.25.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("savePost", function(request, response){
  ...
  Parse.Cloud.run(
    "savePostImage",
    request.params
  ).then(function(savePostImageResult){
  ...
    return Parse.Cloud.run(
      "savePostComment",
      request.params
      );
  })
  ...
}

Parse.Cloud.define("savePostImage",function(request,response){
    ...
    file.save().then(function(savedFileResult){
        response.success(savedFileResult);
    },function(error){
        response.error("saveImage error : " + error);
    });
});


Parse.Cloud.define("savePostComment",function(request,response){
    var userData_objectId = request.params.userData_objectId;
    var user = request.params.user;

    var userData_pointer = request.params.userData_pointer;
    var user_objectId = request.params.user_objectId;

    var comment_text = request.params.comment_text;
    var comment_location = request.params.comment_location;
    ...

    postObject.set("comment_text",comment_text);
    postObject.set("comment_location",comment_location);
    ...

    if(userData_pointer){
      ... 
    } else if(!userData_pointer) {
        // execute query
        Parse.Promise.when(
          Parse.Cloud.run(
            "returnPFUser",
            {"user_objectId":user_objectId}
          ),
          Parse.Cloud.run(
            "returnUserData",
            {"userData_objectId":userData_objectId}
          )
        )
        .then(function(returnPFUserResult,returnedUserData){
            postObject.set("user",returnPFUserResult);

            postObject.set("userData_objectId",userData_objectId);
            postObject.set("userData_pointer",returnedUserData);

            returnedUserData.set("lastPost",postObject);

            // This part seems to occur error
            return Parse.Promise.when([returnedUserData.save(),postObject.save()])
        })
        .then(function(savedUserData,savedPostObject){
          response.success(savedPostObject);
        },function(error){
          response.error(error);
        });
    }
});
```

The error log is below.

```
error: Failed running cloud function savePostComment for user undefined with:
  Input: {"comment_location_latitude":35.75201777186803,"... 
  Error: {"code":141,"message":{}} functionName=savePostComment, code=141, ...

error: Error generating response. ParseError {
  code: 141,
  message: [Error: Cannot create a pointer to an unsaved Object.] } code=141, ...
```

Any ideas appreciated.
Thank you for reading this to the end.

Comment: Just a quick question is  "var user = request.params.user;  var userData_pointer = request.params.userData_pointer"  the current user that  is logged in?

Comment: That seems the problem. Login user is not contained in the request. I'll check them. Thank you so much.

Comment: Correct, you then need to use request.user for current user. Also Parse.User.current() is not available in cloud code. Something to remember.